# three.js display geometry name

Tags: three.js, geometry

i created cube. now, i want to show cube name on it. but i dont know how to do this. please help. sorry for my english.

```
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3,3,3);
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry,cubeMaterial);

cube.name = "cube1";

cube.position.x=-25;
cube.position.y=3;
cube.position.z=0;
scene.add(cube);
```

http://prntscr.com/5ep5h6 this is my cube

http://prntscr.com/5ep5hi what i want to do

Answer (score 1):

I got three options for you: Render the Text as 2D Canvas on the geometry Texture, create a 3D Text or create a Sprite (it's a Canvas too)

```
stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html
stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Text3D.html
stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html
```